# Extending perfect matchings into Hamiltonian cycles

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory, perfect-matchings, hamiltonian-graphs

Let $G$ be a simple cubic graph which has a Hamiltonian circuit $C$.  In general, it is not possible to find a second Hamiltonian circuit which contains all the chords of $C$.  For example, the Wagner graph with $C$ being the outer circuit in the picture contains no such second Hamiltonian circuit.

[image: Wagner graph]

But it is possible to add an additional chord so that the resulting graph contains a second Hamiltonian circuit including all chords, as in the second picture?

[image: Wagner with chord]

Our first question is:

> **Question 1 (EGME)** Let $G$ be a cubic graph which has a Hamiltonian circuit $C$ with a set of chords $D$.  Is it always possible to add a chord $f$ of $C$ in $G$ so that the resulting graph has a Hamiltonian circuit containing all the chords (including the new chord $f$)? Or equivalently, is there a Hamiltonian path containing all the chords in D? Please provide proof or counterexample.

Our second question is

> **Question 2 (EGME)** If we add ANY new set of chords of $C$ in $G$ (as in question 1) which are a perfect matching in the resulting graph (which should be simple), is there a second Hamiltonian circuit which contains all of the chords in the original set? Or equivalently, let $G$ be a 4-regular Hamiltonian graph $G$ with a Hamiltonian circuit $C$, and such that the chords of $C$ can be partitioned into two perfect matchings $P$, $Q$.  Is there a Hamiltonian circuit of $G$ which contains all the edges in $P$ ($Q$).  If not, under what conditions is this true?

Computer experiments seem to suggest this might be the case.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to question 1 is no.  Here are examples of hamiltonian cubic graphs without a hamilton path that contains all the chords of a hamiltonian circuit.  They are smallest possible (there are no examples of graphs with fewer vertices for which the answer to the question is no ... this was exhaustively checked).

[image: examples]

Question 2 remains open.